# Error with getting data field from database

Tags: php, mysql

I am using this code in my model to get `user_id` of logged-in user from register table:

```
   function get_user_id()
{
    $this->db->select('user_id');
    $this->db->from('register');
    $this->db->where('username', $this->session->userdata('username')); 
    $query = $this->db->get();
}
```

and I am using it in my controller to insert the `user_id` of the logged-in user in another table that is using `user_id` as foreign key.

```
public function event_desc()
{       
    $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class="error">', '</div>');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('event_title','Event Title','required|max_length[40]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('event_desc','Event Description','required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('event_cat','Event Category','required|callback_is_default');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('event_date','Event Date','required|date');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('event_venue','Event Venue','required|max_length[25]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('event_charges','Event Charges','required');
    if($this->form_validation->run()== FALSE)
    { 

        $this->add_event();
    }
    else
    {
        $this->load->model('event_model');  
            $u_id=$this->event_model->get_user_id();
                $data=array(
                'cat_id '=> $this->input->post('event_cat'),
                'user_id' => $u_id,
                'event_title' => $this->input->post('event_title'),
                'event_desc' => $this->input->post('event_desc'),
                'event_date' => $this->input->post('event_date'),
                'event_venue' => $this->input->post('event_venue'),
                'event_charges' => $this->input->post('event_charges'),
                );
            $this->event_model->add_event_record($data);
            $this->is_logged_in();


    }

}
```

When I submit the form,the following error is displayed:

```
A Database Error Occurred
Error Number: 1048
Column 'user_id' cannot be null
INSERT INTO `tbl_events` (`cat_id` , `user_id`, `event_title`, `event_desc`,
    `event_date`, `event_venue`, `event_charges`) VALUES ('2', NULL, 'vhbnjkm',
     'vhbnjkm', '2070/09/09', 'jfhsk', 'hsj')
Filename: C:/xampp/htdocs/event-tracker/application/models/event_model.php
Line Number: 6
```

Please help me to sort the problem:

Comment: The answer is (*most likely*) in the error message.

Comment: check the model returns anything `$this->event_model->get_user_id();`

Comment: may be it returns a null value

Comment: Yeah! It returns null.Why so?

Answer (score 0):

You have to insert your user_id since it appears to be forgein key of another table. If you want to leave at null you should change your logic

Comment: Is there any other way to get the user_id of logged_in user.

Comment: You could save it in session

Comment: Is there any other way to get the user_id of the logged_in users?

Comment: I havent save it in session.I have set the username in the session.The user_id is auto generated for the registered user.

Comment: When you create a user you then get new inserted ID of the user and you can save that in session or just do a query you want

Comment: Its tedious and hard for each user to generate a unique id for each registration as user_id is integer.

Comment: You dont have to. Set Auto increment in a database as settings of id attribute and unique.

Answer (score 0):

there could be two possibilities

1 the way of getting userID is not valid , use following code  to get ID

```
$this->current_user->id
```

2 you should First Check Either user is Logged in or not

Comment: Ya ofcourse! the user is logged in.This form can be filled only by the loggedin users.